Powershell not initializing
I am using an app System Scheduler to orchestrate jobs on Windows 10 VMWare virtual machine. I came back from vacation and a business user said, "Hey, I haven't gotten any notifications that the jobs have completed and the data is stale". I log into the VM and there are lots of PowerShell sessions open, but no text to indicate PowerShell initialized. Just a static cursor. So I think to myself, "Why don't I try running the job interactively,". So I start a new PowerShell session, but the prompt never appears, just a static, unblinking cursor. What would cause PowerShell to not initialize?

check your system logs. Try running powershell.exe from a CMD shell to see if you get different results. Ensure you're up to date with windows patches (and have rebooted since.)
Run procmon with appropriate filters and see if something is failing or timing out.

It appears that the sysadmins pushed a major version change to Windows but didn't tell anyone. When I rebooted there was a significant change and Powershell functionality returned. When all else fails, try turning it off and on again.
